# Вывести элементы списка

Tags: c#

В консольном приложении создано несколько объектов, подписанных на событие. Нужно выяснить,для каких объектов сработал обработчик событий и вывести их имя. Для этого решил создать список и метод,который добавляет в этот список подписанные события. Но выводятся не имена а "имя_сборки".Person.

```
List<Person> allPersons = new List<Person>();

    public void AddPersonToOffice(Person person)
    {
        if (allPersons.Contains(person))
            return;
        allPersons.Add(person);
        this.EmpoyerComeIn += person.IsComing;


        foreach (var all in allPersons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(all);
        }
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(all.Name);`

Comment: Вопрос, если я вызываю этот метод в Main, office.AddPersonToOffice();, что нужно передать в метод,чтобы он выводил имена всех объектов?

Comment: Вопрос - я телепат или я не телепат? Немножко телепат. Туда надо передать объект типа `Person`, который не содержится в списке `allPersons`.

Comment: Тогда получается выведется имя только этого объекта, так? А если таких объектов несколько? Допустим                                               Person firstPerson = new Person("Том"); office.AddPersonToOffice(firstPerson);

Comment: нет, выведутся имена всех объектов, содержащихся в списке `allPersons`. Попробуйте.

Comment: пробовал перед тем как написать первый комментарий. видимо я неправильно формулирую вопрос( в любом случае спасибо, с Name помогли